# Anycharts - Ratio of Bars in the bar charts is not proper

Tags: charts, anychart

In Bar charts of Anychart if the values of bars are small, for instance there are two bars one has a count of 1 and the other has count of 2 than the bar size are not proportional. And same value is displayed multiple times in the Y axis. Like multple 1's and 2's are displayed in the y axis, and the messed up part is one bar is mapped to lowwer end of 1 and 2nd bar is mapped to upper end of the 2.Can any one please help me with these.
I tried to make the Y axis to start from zero always but it doesn't seems to help.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need to change the auto_calculation_mode attribute value to "smart":

```
<y_axis>
   <scale auto_calculation_mode="Smart" />
</y_axis>
```